# I need to execute a particular test before and after all the tests in project. Is there any maven plugin that supports my need?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-plugin

I need to execute a particular test before and after all the tests in project. Is there any maven plugin that supports my need?

I am using TestNg for my tests.

If any one have some info on this, please help me with your answers.

Comment: Is it a "test" you want to execute before and after all the tests? If it's just a set of actions (a method) to be performed, then you've got annotations in TestNg (@BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite) to do that. If it's indeed a test, then here's a kinda hack: TestNG executes tests in alphabetical order of fully-qualified method name. So for example com.mycompany.tests.AAFirstTest.testAFirst can execute first and com.mycompany.tests.ZZLastTest.testZLast can execute last if other tests are named reasonably well.

Comment: I would suggest to use @BeforeTest instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @BeforeSuite to run it before any of the tests have been run and @AfterSuite to run after the tests have been done.